# ImportError: cannot import name 'ExponentialSmoothing'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try

```
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing, SimpleExpSmoothing, Holt
```

on jupyter-notebook.

In python it is ok, but isn't ok on jupyter

Comment: You probably have two different intepreters, between your built-in python and your notebook . What is the result of `import sys; print(sys.executable)` in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

Consider updating your statsmodels using following command for `pip`:

```
pip install statsmodels==0.9.0
```

And for `Anaconda`, use following command:

```
conda install statsmodels==0.9.0
```

**NOTE for Jupyter**

After updating the package or installing import it as

```
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing, SimpleExpSmoothing, Holt
```